# Google family account can login to gmail, can't login to chrome

Tags: google-account, google-family-link

I installed Google Family Link on my phone. I created a child account for my kid. I can sign into it with Gmail, but not with Chromium Sync. I do not have a device to associate with the account. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using a phone app not about using a web application as it's defined in [help/on-topic]. This question might be on-topic in [android.se] or [apple.se].

Comment: @Rubén: There's also a Google Family Link web application.  [(Source.)](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/41482/how-to-manage-your-childs-google-family-link-settings-using-a-web-browser#41483)  Therefore, I wonder if you could please reopen this question?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know, [how these under 13 accounts work](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7106787). I would definitely recommend to check supervision setting. As you mentioned you already have a Family Link app on your phone:

1. Open the Family Link app Family Link.
2. In the top left, tap Menu and then Family group.
3. Tap the name of the family member

You can either follow **Manage Settings** link > More > **Controls for signing in** and disable parental supervise for logging in. You could also explore **Help and feedback** section to find there any chrome specific problematics.

Alternatively you can click **Account information** > Edit and temporarily change your child's birthday to be above 13 years ([or applicable age in your country](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1350409?)) [actually one day before birthday and wait one day]. Then you should be able to sign in for example through InPrivate/Incognito window via a chrome desktop browser because this account is treated as an adult since then. Let me know if this helps, I can elaborate more.